# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _N@8 referenced in function _SUM5

Tags: visual-studio, dll, fortran, unresolved-external

I am using `FORTRAN` to write codes for `ASPEN plus`. I created a code in `FORTRAN` and there was no problem in compiling it and creating the `.obj` files. However when the linking process has been tested I got this error. Here comes all the lines I got in the `.dl` file.

```
-------------------- sum5.lnk ------------------------------
  "sum5.obj"
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\atdms.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\zemath.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\zesqp.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\zereport.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\ppmon.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\pputil.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\ppupp.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\zeftools.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\zevaraccu.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\ppflash.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\ppexec.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\zeshs.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\pprxn.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\ppbase.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\ppeos.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\zeuosutl.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\zestreamu.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\zeitutl.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\pppces.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\ppstub.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\zeusrutl.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\pptgs.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\atdms2.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\aphier.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\pptransport.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\ppelec.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\pphysysprop.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\ppgamma.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\tabledatawrapper.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\ASPENP~2.3\Engine\lib\zeuser3.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\ASPENP~2.3\Engine\lib\zeratefrac.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\pppoly.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\ASPENP~2.3\Engine\lib\zerplug.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\ASPENP~2.3\Engine\lib\zercstr.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\ASPENP~2.3\Engine\lib\zerbatch.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\ASPENP~2.3\Engine\lib\zeu3utils.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\zepml.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\aosbridge.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\ASPENP~2.3\Engine\lib\zeu3dl.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\ASPENP~2.3\Engine\lib\zeopi.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\ppncsolid.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\ASPENP~2.3\Engine\lib\rtpdfutl.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\OOMFV7~1.3\\lib\oomfutils.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\ppada.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\ASPENP~2.3\Engine\lib\zerxrplus.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\ppfact.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\ASPENP~2.3\Engine\lib\zeradfrac.lib
    C:\PROGRA~2\ASPENT~1\APRSYS~1.3\Engine\lib\pptderefprop.lib
    libifcoremd.lib
    libifportmd.lib
    libmmd.lib
    msvcrt.lib
  -------------------- sum5.dyl ------------------------------
    EXPORTS _SUM5=_SUM5@120
    EXPORTS _SUM5@120
-------------------- Link command ------------------------------
     link /DLL /nologo /out:"sum5.dll" 
     /def:"sum5.dyl" -nodefaultlib:libifcore.lib -nodefaultlib:libifport.lib -   nodefaultlib:libm.lib -nodefaultlib:libifcoremt.lib -nodefaultlib:libmmt.lib
     -nodefaultlib:libc.lib @"sum5.lnk"
-------------------- Link message ------------------------------
    Creating library sum5.lib and object sum5.exp
    sum5.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _N@8 referenced in function _SUM5  
    sum5.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    Link failure, status = 1120
    asplink return code = 5
```

In the last link message you can see the error. Do you think if there is something wrong with the content of the code or the compatibility of the `FORTRAN` and the compiler which is `Visual Studio` is of question?

```
  SUBROUTINE sum5 (SOUT, NSUBS, IDXSUB, ITYPE, NINTK, INTK, NREALK,
 2                REALK, IDS, NPO, NBOPST, NIWK, IWK, NWK, WK,
 3                NC, NR , STOIC, RATES, FLUXM, FLUXS, XCURR,
 4                NTCAT, RATCAT, NTSSAT, RATSSA, KCALL,
 *                KFAIL, KFLASH, NCOMP)

  IMPLICIT real*8 (A-H, O-Z)
  INTEGER NSUBS, NINTK, NPO, NIWK, NWK, NC, NR, MIM, NCOMP
  INTEGER I, J

   DIMENSION SOUT(40),IDXSUB(NSUBS),ITYPE(NSUBS),INK(NINTK),
 1           REALK(NREALK) ,IDS(2,1) ,NBOPST(6,NPO) ,IWK(NIWK),
 2           WK(NWK),STOIC(NSUBS,NC,NR),RATES(50,50)

  #include "ppexec_user.cmn"

  EQUIVALENCE (RMISS, USER_RUMISS)
  EQUIVALENCE (IMISS, USER_IUMISS)
  #include "dms_ncomp.cmn"

  #include "dms_maxwrt.cmn"


  REAL Ri,PA,N, Ti, M(100)
  REAL k(100,100), keq, NU(100,100)
  REAL R(100,100), P(100,100), X(100)
  REAL Xin(100), t, h, k9, tim(100)
  REAL Pi(100), K1(100,100), K2(100,100)
  REAL K3(100,100), K4(100,100), RATES(100,100)


  DIMENSION INDX(1)
  FLOW=SOUT(NCOMP_NCC+1)
  T = SOUT(NCOMP_NCC+2)
  PA = SOUT(NCOMP_NCC + 3)

   CALL PPMON_VOLV (T,PA,RESLTS,NCPM,INDX,NBOPST, 3, 1,
 1 VOLM,D2, KER)

  R=8.314
```

Comment: Which Fortran compiler do you use? Which version of VS? Do you get  any warnings (when warning level is at maximum level) when you compile sum5.obj? Do you use (external/undeclared) function N in your sum5 file? sum5 file is Fortran file?

Comment: Sum5 is the fortran 5 and my Fortran is 9 and VS 2008, but the point is I have already compiled and linked other fortran files in this combination!

Comment: sum5 is a fortran subroutine. There is just one parameter N in it and not a function!

Comment: The @8 suffix indicates that you are compiling with options that specify the STDCALL calling convention. Can you show us the source of sum5, or at least the declaration section? I note that the error talks about _SUM5, so you're not building everything with STDCALL, so I wonder what is going on here. Usually, link errors such as this (ignoring the @8 part) are due to having a reference to an array that isn't declared as an array. You say N is a "parameter" - probably you mean dummy argument in Fortran terminology - but if that was the case you would never get this error.

Comment: "Sum5 is the fortran 5 and my Fortran is 9" What **exactly** do you mean?

Comment: @peter that was a mistake in typing. sum5 is the name of the fortran subroutine.

Comment: @SteveLionel Here comes the declaration part:

Comment: DIMENSION SOUT(40),IDXSUB(NSUBS),ITYPE(NSUBS),INK(NINTK),
     1           REALK(NREALK) ,IDS(2,1) ,NBOPST(6,NPO) ,IWK(NIWK),
     2           WK(NWK),STOIC(NSUBS,NC,NR),RATES(50,50)
C
#include "ppexec_user.cmn"
C
      EQUIVALENCE (RMISS, USER_RUMISS)
      EQUIVALENCE (IMISS, USER_IUMISS)
#include "dms_ncomp.cmn"
#include "dms_maxwrt.cmn"
     
      REAL Ri,PA,N, Ti, M(100)
      REAL k(100,100), keq, NU(100,100)
      REAL R(100,100), P(100,100), X(100)
      REAL Xin(100), t, h, k9, tim(100)
      REAL Pi(100), K1(100,100), K2(100,100)
      REAL K3(100,100), K4(100,100), RATES(100,100)

Comment: @SteveLionel I am not sure if it is understandable in this way I copied and pasted here from the original code!

Comment: append it to your question with "code" formatting. This way it is hardly readable

Comment: `N` you have shown in code is a local variable that is not causing your problem. Do you have another `N`?

Comment: @Peter could be a part of codes that I mistakenly used N(1,2) in the correlation? or should it be written in a certain form that would cause this problem? Because as I said there was no problem in compiling it, this message is given in the linking afterwards

Comment: Please show the SUBROUTINE statement for SUM5. My guess is that N does not appear in the argument list for the subroutine, in which case the error is understandable. But I also wonder if perhaps your SUM5 was compiled by Digital Visual Fortran 5 and you are now using Intel Visual Fortran 9 (14 is current). If so, these don't mix - you have to recompile all your Fortran sources with the Intel compiler.

Comment: Oh, now I see that you do show the partial code for SUM5 in the original question. N is NOT a dummy argument of SUM5, so a reference to N(1,2) looks like a function call with two arguments.

Comment: so you mean that this N (1,2) could be the source of this problem? because now I corrected that but I did not check the linking yet.

Comment: Yes, that is almost certainly the source of the problem.

Comment: As a side comment: never, ever, use implicit declarations - and always put "implicit none" at the beginning of every program/function/module... It may be tedious, but it can help prevent many problems - though not this one :-)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help and comments :) It really helped me :)